# moving from fork() to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, fork

I'm trying to move from `fork()` model to threading in my application. Following is an example of my `fork()` code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void worker()
{
  std::cout<<"\nworker thread\n";
}

int start()
{
  pid_t pid;
  if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    return -1;
  }

  if(pid != 0) {
    while(1) {
      worker();

      sleep(5);
    }
  }

}


int main()
{
  std::cout << "\nstarting...\n" << std::endl;
  start();
  std::cout << "\nend...\n" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I was wondering if this is possible with threading, where the main function can continue and call other functions and the thread sleeps for `x` seconds and calls the worker ?

Intended output:

```
starting...


thread

end...


thread
```

and continues.

This is the threading code I have made up to now, the issue I have is that control never comes back to main unless I join the thread and that would mean the thread is not running anymore. But i want that `start()` thread to continue in the background

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void* worker(void *data)
{
std::cout<<"\nthread\n";
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int start()
{

  pthread_t thread;

  while(1){

    if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL,worker,NULL)){
        printf("\nError creating thread\n");
        return -1;
      }
          sleep(10);


  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);

}


int main()
{
  std::cout << "\nstarting...\n" << std::endl;
  start();
  std::cout << "\nending...\n" << std::endl;
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm failing to understand what you mean. Have you made any attempts of translating that program into a single process, multi-threaded approach?

Comment: Yes I have, and I can post the code for that

Comment: Yes, you write a function that does `while(1) { worker(); sleep(5); }` and specify that as an argument when you create your thread. What part of the `std::thread` documentation are you having trouble with?

Comment: Why would you switch working code that uses `fork()` to use threads? You lose the advantage of having separate address spaces. What are you gaining?

Comment: @JishnuUNair Why are you calling `pthread_create` in a loop? Are you trying to create more than one thread?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm just learning how to use threading, my intention was totally to understand if this is possible with threading

Comment: @JishnuUNair The primary flaw is you're missing a `thread::join()`  call from your foreground  thread.

Comment: @RobK _"What are you gaining?"_ Threads are actually way more lightweight than forking child processes?

Comment: If I do thread::join wouldn't that stop the thread ?? My intention was to make the thread run in the background when the main thread can call other function

Comment: @JishnuUNair But you have no other functions for the main thread to call. So how can we show where that code would go?

Comment: Instead of using the non-portable (and in my opinion rather unpleasant) pthread interface, you could consider using std::thread. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ On Windows? yes. On Linux? I don't know now, and certainly not originally.

Comment: @RobK Child processes are ***always*** more heavy regarding resource consumption, regardless or the OS. Think about all those duplicated resources like environment variables, predefined file descriptors, etc ...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hi, if you see the intended output I have posted, you will see the "end..." is printed in between the "thread" using fork(), I would like to do the same with threading

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But, on the flipside, there's contention for modification to shared resources such as the shared address space mapping which you don't have with separate processes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Process creation via `fork()` was originally very simple and fast. `fork()` caused the process image to be written to the virtual memory and then immediately that image was loaded back in at a different location. That's what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

void worker()
{
    std::cout << "Hello.\n";
}


int main()
{
    std::thread t{worker}; // spawn a thread to call worker
    std::cout << "Boo.\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{1});
    t.join(); // wait for t to exit.
    return 0;
}
```